# Sharing memory between 32-bit and 64-bit processes in Windows

Tags: c++, memory

I am facing a problem of sharing memory between two processes running under Windows 64-bit

The goal is to share a memory mapping created using a 32-bit process, which the 64-bit process writes to.

I am using the following to create the memory under the 32-bit application:

```
m_hSharedFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, NULL, BUF_SIZE, memName);
m_pSharedBuf = MapViewOfFile(m_hSharedFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

And the following in the 64-bit application for opening the shared memory:

```
m_hSharedFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, m_memName.c_str());
m_pSharedBuf = MapViewOfFile(m_hSharedFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

(Edited) The problem is the data written in the 64-bit process doesn't match the data read by the host 32-bit process.

When I try to run the same programs as 32-bit <--> 32-bit, the memory mapping works fine, and the data is received with no problems.

I guess the problem resides in the memory addressing. Are there any workarounds to resolve this problem?

**Update:**
The problem is resolved. The data structure that represents the shared memory was the follwoing:

```
struct SH_MEM {
     size_t size;
     size_t max_size;
/***/
}
```

I missed the fact that `size_t` is architecture-dependent (4 bytes for 32-bit apps and 8 bytes for 64-bit apps).

I forced the data types to be 4 bytes, using `int32_t` instead (with header file `cstdint`).

Comment: Do you get any error from your system calls? If so, what is the value of `GetLastError()`?

Comment: I expected to get exceptions or errors when trying to access the memory, however I didn't get any problems at all while running both processes (In the original code, each line is been checked for NULL pointers, I just omitted them in the question for the length).
The memory is being accessible in each process, however the data contained is different..
I will keep trouble shooting and post updates regarding that.

Comment: You can try calling `FlushViewOfFile()`. I'm not sure if it helps with shared memory or only with file-backed maps, but it is worth a try.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @xaxxon, sorry I guess I am weary that I forgot to state my problem clearly, I updated the question. Thanks for the notice though!

Comment: you say it doesn't match.. how does it differ?  is it seemingly random?  or is iit related in some way just not correct?

Comment: The data I am capturing in the 32-bit app seems in totally different memory space, I mean the data that is supposed to be written via the 64-bit doesn't show up in the 32-bit process.

Comment: When its 32-bit <--> 32-bit case using the exact same code, it works. however as in my target case 32-bit <--> 64-bit, it doesn't work..

Comment: You haven't answered xaxxon's question. How does it differ? Does the 64-bit program write "01 02 03" and the 32-bit program gets "01 00 02 00 03"? Or does the 32-bit program get "00 00 00"? You'll probably need to share more code (like the part that reads and writes the data) to get to the bottom of the problem,

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. My fault that I didn't post the data structure I am using to represent the shared memory in my question. 
I will update the question with the resolution. It turned out to be data structure miss representation for 32-bit and 64-bit. One of the members in the structure was of type (size_t) which I missed that it is different between 64-bit (8 bytes) and 32-bit (4 bytes).
I normalized the data structure to use data type (int32_t) to strict it to 4 bytes.
Problem resolved. Thanks again!

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks Ray for the comment, it was the tip of the thread for me to look for the problem by checking data structure!

Comment: *Always* use fixed width data types when communication with something else, you never know what type of system the "something else" is.

Comment: I agree with @JanHenke. Take a look at<stdint.h> that contains common fixed data type definitions

Comment: This is why we wanted clarification. You wrote "the data that is supposed to be written via the 64-bit doesn't show up in the 32-bit process." But in fact this statement was false. The data is showing up, it's just showing up corrupted.

Comment: @yamens,  Thank you very much. Your post  helped me address the same issue  faced by me recently.